# Regular Background Task iOS

Tags: ios, background

I am creating an iOS App which needs to check for a Wifi-Connection on a regular bases while the app is in background mode. So I'm looking for a background task which allows to run a couple lines of code f.ex. every minute.

I've looked through the Apple Docs and of course Google to find out a long running background task but without success. 
Do someone knows a techniques to do this?

Comment: It is pretty difficult to believe you did proper search because if I type into google "iOS long ru" not only will it complete it for me to "iOS long running background task" but the solution is right in front of me in the 1st and 2nd result.

Answer (score 0):

for ios7+ go for background refresh to run some code at 'regular' intervals

Answer (score -1):

Only some special app can run in background,such as music or voip...